# Вход или регистрация через Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хочу подсветить поле ввода, в котором была ошибка. Например если email неправильный то изменить класс поля. Как это сделать правильно?

```
<%= f.email_field :email, class: "text" %>
<%= f.password_field :password, class: "text" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если просто, то это выглядит так:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, class: "text #{'has_errors' if f.object.errors.messages.has_key?(:email) }" %>
<%= f.password_field :password, class: "text #{'has_errors' if f.object.errors.messages.has_key?(:password) }" %>
```

Правильно будет вынести всю обработку ошибок в хелпер.
Я использую f.object, поскольку из контекста неясно имя переменной объекта, подозреваю, что это @user.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте gem https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

```
<%= f.error :email %>
```

Подсвечивает required поля